# Laravel unknown column

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have a problem with this error:

```
https://pastebin.com/cgm5yq0P
```

This is my form:

```
https://pastebin.com/bSU5X5EC
```

This is my web.php (route controller):

`Route::post('/komentarz', 'VideosController@postComment');`

This is my VideoController postComment function:

```
https://pastebin.com/SYbEjB8H
```

This is my Comment model:

```
https://pastebin.com/SxHX6gTP
```

This is my User model comments function:

```
    public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
```

This is my Video model comments function:

`public function comments(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Comment')->withTimestamps();
    }`

And finally, Migration file named create_comments_table:

`https://pastebin.com/2cHscQfq`

My Routes:
 `https://pastebin.com/ki8FZ0C6`
Please help me with this.. I dunno what is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your foreign keys are wrong. Change your migration to this.

```
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

$table->unsignedInteger('video_id');
$table->foreign('video_id')->references('id')->on('videos')->onDelete('cascade');
```

**Edit** : This adds the comment and attaches it to the video and user.

```
// model fillable property

protected $fillable = [
    'text', 'user_id', 'video_id',
];

// route
Route::post('/film/{id}/komentarz', 'VideosController@postComment');

// controller method
public function postComment(CreateCommentRequest $request, $id)
{
    $video = Video::findOrFail($id);

    $video->comments()->create([
        'text' => $request->text,
        'user_id' => auth()->id(),
    ]);

    return 'works';
}

// form
{!! Form::open(['url' => "/film/{$video->id}/komentarz", 'method' => 'post','class' => 'form-horizontal']) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-3 control-label">
        {!! Form::label('text', 'Treść komentarza:') !!}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        {!! Form::textarea('text', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'size' => '5x5']) !!}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-3">
        {!! Form::submit('Dodaj', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-comment']) !!}
    </div>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Works, tanks a lot :D

Comment: but can you tell me how I can get comments for this video?

Comment: @KurtCobain the way you add comments is wrong. You're not linking the comment to a video. The comment should fail since you have foreign keys. Post your routes to the question and i'll show you how to add comments to videos based on that.

Comment: And comments to video I get by using $video->comments?

Comment: @KurtCobain yes

Comment: Its not works:  QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel.comment_video' doesn't exist (SQL: select `comments`.*, `comment_video`.`video_id` as `pivot_video_id`, `comment_video`.`comment_id` as `pivot_comment_id`, `comment_video`.`created_at` as `pivot_created_at`, `comment_video`.`updated_at` as `pivot_updated_at` from `comments` inner join `comment_video` on `comments`.`id` = `comment_video`.`comment_id` where `comment_video`.`video_id` = 1)

Comment: @KurtCobain your relationship is wrong. It's tried to make a belongs to many query from video to comments, which should be one to many. Make sure your comments relationship in your video model uses `hasMany`.

Answer (score 0):

in comment model i see 'user' in fillable, not 'user_id'. i think it should be user_id. or you could use

```
protected guarded = [];
```

instead of using `fillable` array.